# How to create a popup view in django?

Tags: python, html, django, orm

I'd like to create a popup to see the detailed information coming from a view when I click on the link.

**kpiMonitoring.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load humanize %}

{% block refresh %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="240">
{% endblock refresh %}

{% block title %}
<title>SMD/PBA - SMD KPI MONITORING</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<h3>SMD-CE KPI MONITORING</h3>

<h5><input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" class="btn btn-dark" style="float:left;" value="REFRESH">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="copy-table-button" data-clipboard-target="#mytable1"
            style="float:left;">COPY TO EXCEL
    </button>

    <a href="" bgcolor="#0080ff" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; color:Red;">Over: {{ timeOverOver }} </a>   

     {% if timeOverWaitSAOI > 0 %}
    <a href="" bgcolor="#0080ff" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; color:blue;">SAOI: {{ timeOverWaitSAOI }} &nbsp</a>
    {% else %}
    <a></a>
    {% endif %}

     {% if timeOverWaitMAOI > 0 %}
    <a href="" bgcolor="#0080ff" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; color:blue;">MAOI: {{ timeOverWaitMAOI }} &nbsp</a>
    {% else %}
    <a></a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if timeOverWaitPAOI > 0 %}
    <a href="" bgcolor="#0080ff" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; color:blue;">PAOI: {{ timeOverWaitPAOI }} &nbsp</a>
    {% else %}
    <a></a>
    {% endif %}

    <a style="float:right; color:black;">Time Over + 2hs &nbsp</a>
</h5>
```

**views.py**

```
from kpi.models import TimeOver

def kpiMonitoringView(request):

timeOver = TimeOver.objects.filter(mfg_part_code='P12121', over_status='Time Over')
timeWait = TimeOver.objects.filter(mfg_part_code='P12121', over_status = 'Wait')

timeOverWait = timeWait.count()
timeOverWaitPAOI = timeWait.filter(insp_loc ='P').count()
timeOverWaitMAOI = timeWait.filter(insp_loc='M').count()
timeOverWaitSAOI = timeWait.filter(insp_loc='S').count()

timeOverOver = timeOver.count()

return render(request,'kpi/kpiMonitoring.html','timeOverWait':timeOverWait, 'timeOverOver':timeOverOver,'timeOverWaitPAOI':timeOverWaitPAOI,'timeOverWaitMAOI':timeOverWaitMAOI, 
timemeOverWaitSAOI':timeOverWaitSAOI})
```

**models.py**

```
class TimeOver(models.Model):
work_ymd = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
insp_loc = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
line_nm = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
mfg_part_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
bcd_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
work_dt = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
over_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'time_over'
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import kpiMonitoringView

    urlpatterns = [
    path('kpiMonitoringView/',kpiMonitoringView, name="kpiMonitoringView"),
]
```

So, when someone click in "PAOI" link for example, the page will show a popup with the follow atributes of the models.py: line_nm, bcd_id, work_dt, over_status.

Comment: you could take a look at boostrap model https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Hello @ngawang13, thanks for your advice, I used it and it's working for this proposal.